# Solution to $z^4-z(1-i)^8=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

$$z^4-z(1-i)^8=0$$

I was thinking to find a way to place $z$ in one side and $1-i$ in other side then I can use the polar (trigonometric) form. But I don't know how to find that way. Anyway I welcome any other idea if you can help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor the $z$ like this
$$z (z^3 - (1-i)^7) = 0.$$

Then the solutions are $z=0$, and the solution of $z^3 = (1-i)^7$. You can use the polar form to solve that.

Comment: You shouldn't change the exponent on $1-i$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be $(1-i)^8$

Answer (score 3):

Note $(1-i)^8=(-2i)^4=(-4)^2=16$. The roots of $z(z^3-16)=0$ are $0$ and $2\sqrt[3]{2}$ times the three roots of unity. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thank youuusp muchh